# JSON.NET - Getting nested values

Tags: json.net

I have a JSON something like this:

```
  {
    "key": "Target",
    "value": {
      "__type": "Entity:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "key": "prioritycode",
          "value": {
            "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
            "Value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "completeinternalreview",
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "key": "stepname",
          "value": "10-Lead"
        },
        {
          "key": "createdby",
          "value": {
            "__type": "EntityReference:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
            "Id": "ca2ead0c-8786-e511-80f9-3863bb347b18",
            "KeyAttributes": [],
            "LogicalName": "systemuser",
            "Name": null,
            "RowVersion": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

How do the toke for the key/values by searching for the value of the key?

Eg I want to get the key value pair 'completeinternalreview'

Comment: After you deserialized your JSON string you have an object with `value.Attributes` on which you can perform a simple LINQ query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a C# class like this to represent that attributes object from your JSON:

```
public class MyValue
{
    [JsonProperty("Attributes")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

you can simply deserialize the string:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, MyValue>>(jsonString);
```

and then find the correct key-value pair with:

```
var kvp = result.Value.Attributes.Find(a => a.Value == "completeinternalreview");
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed !